# Javascript to send notice to discord based on webpage last updated

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm attempting to create a page that when it's been updated, it sends a notice to a channel in discord. I have a working page with a button that will send a notice to discord(uses webhooks and javascript). I'm stuck on executing use of document.lastModified to detect when the page was last updated so that it can execute the onclick=sendMessage(). Any/all help with this would be appreciated.

-Matt

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Discord Webhook Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
  </body>

  <script>
  mess1= document.lastModified;
  math=99;
  x = hidden(mess1);
  if (x == true)
     {
     
    function sendMessage() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/736073177125355570/yn5upyFa_7IkqwRXlO9XPzooIyMWkqM7wIXcIjqSR6SlhYD8eBCWOm7vEVl4vmNjQBxL");

      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

      var params = {
        username: "Update Bot",
        avatar_url: "",
        content: "Testing bot... updating..."
      }

      request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    }
    
     }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the `lastModified` value somewhere to be able to compare it.

The only value that you have in the DOM is the current one.

You could do this:

```
const current = document.lastModified;

// Get the last known modified timestamp
const previous = localStorage.getItem('lastModified');

// Update the current modified timestamp
localStorage.setItem('lastModified', current);

// If they differ, trigger the webhook
if (current !== previous) { 
  doTheXHRThing();
}
```

Comment: That was the missing thing, thanks for that. I have that now set to body onload so it executes on page load